# Is it compulsory to learn C/C++ before learning PHP?

Tags: php, c++, c

Can someone PHP Developer tell me? , what is better for me to learn PHP ??

Websites, Tutorials, or any other good information, which is helpful for me to learn PHP..

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: The question in the title at least has a definitive answer. No.

Answer (score 7):

No. You can learn whatever language you want first. PHP is arguable easier to learn for a beginner than C or C++, but beginners learn  them as their first language all the time.

Knowing any other programming may help you learn PHP more quickly, but none are required.

PHP.net is a good resource for the standard library, and it provides a language reference as well. That is all I ever needed to use to learn the language from scratch.

Comment: Not necessarily true. The whole "learn one syntax, learn them all" argument IMO is moot. The problem is people will try to apply their knowledge in one domain to another and see that it's not so easily transferable. You will spend more time reading the docs for language-specific information than you will learning the language.

Comment: I never said learn one learn them all. I meant only that the process of learning one language makes one learn to think in a different way. This makes it easier to adapt to new syntax for sure, but it definitely does not cancel the learning curve.

Comment: @remyabel I changed it to "may" in any case to tone it down.